# give a scanf input string for a c code execution with makefile

Tags: c, shell, input, makefile, scanf

I'm trying to write my first makefile to completely automate my code execution. I have a single c code (BootstrapCL.c) that I have to execute multiple time; for each execution I should give in input (I have 2 scanf inside the c code) a file name (with and without extension). I have to repeat this operation for all the file inside the folder (say a group of cvs files).

This is my makefile

```
SRCS := $(wildcard *.csv)
BINS := $(SRCS:%.csv=%)

all: ${BINS}

%: BootstrapCL.c
    gcc -Wall BootstrapCL.c  -lm -o BootstrapCL
    ./BootstrapCL 
    $@.csv 
    $@
```

The problem is that when makefile arrive to the line :
`./BootstrapCL`  the shell wait for the input and so I cannot reach the nexts line to give this inputs by the makefile itself. How can I solve this problem and obtain an automatic process?

Comment: makefiles are generally used to build software. I would suggest using a shell script to find the csv files and pass the filenames to your executable.

Comment: A normal technique would be to have your `BootstrapCL` program accept multiple file name arguments, and for it to process each file name in turn (using `argv` in `main()`, not reading with `scanf()`), and then use `./BootstrapCL *.csv` to process all the file names in the directory. Given no arguments, it might read file names from standard input, or it might read standard input for the data (think of `cat`, or `grep`), or it might object "I need to be given one or more file names on the command line". All have their merits; I'd probably go with "process standard input as data" or "complain".

Comment: I would like to try fixing this problem before considering a totally different option restarting from 0 (such as Bash script); I'm not saying that bash script is not a good option, but If I can fix the problem I posted I'll fulfill my purpose

Comment: Processing command line arguments will make the program more generally useful.  Making people type to standard input annoys after, oh, the second execution.  You've got an answer on how to do it from a makefile, but it is an abuse of makefiles.

Comment: You get the point Jonathan Leffler; your solution also works well. Any idea to prevent makefile from execute, as last target, "all"?; I'm not sure but I think that this is due to my wrong use of $@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the inputs to the program.

```
%: BootstrapCL.c
    gcc -Wall BootstrapCL.c  -lm -o BootstrapCL
    (echo $@.csv ; echo $@) | ./BootstrapCL
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar ; One last question: makefile also execute, in the end, the target "all"; of course i don't have any file "all.csv", I think that the issue came from the use of $@, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Maybe instead of `%:` use `$(BINS):`